# How to ping an EC2 instance running in the same vpc same subnet but different security group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

How to ping an EC2 instance A from instance B running in the same VPC, same subnet but different security group in AWS, both are running on the public subnet, I am able to ping to the instance A private IP  from B if I add the CIDR blocking range of the VPC but not the public IP and I want to hit the public IP

Comment: What are the ingress and egress rules on the SGs?

Comment: ingress rules means ? i have put all traffic icmp but not put 0.0.0.0 i have just put the instance B security group in it

Comment: Instance B can keep on keep on changing but the security group will remain the same

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't allow `0.0.0.0/0` how would ping over the public IP exactly accessed the instance?

Comment: But if i allow 0.0.0.0 any one over internet can ping but i want to allow  only those instances which belong to the particular security group

Comment: I even attached the B security group to the instance A so now A and B are in same security group , but still its not working

Comment: SG to SG traffic is only for private networking, not over the internet. Instead of `0.0.0.0/0` just allow the public IP of the first instance.

Comment: That works ,  i have checked but the instances will keep on changing so their public ip will also change

Comment: Setup Elastic IP on the source instance. But if they are in same VPC, why not just use private networking?

Comment: Also if you don't mind, I would like to provide the answer for future reference based on the comments.

Comment: **Hint:** Using `PING` to diagnose network problems isn't normally a great idea because networks often block ICMP traffic. It would be better to test with the network port that you _actually_ want to use. For example, if it's a web server, then test an HTTP request on port 80. If you want to login to the instance, then test SSH on port 22. Using Ping just leads to extra work for potentially no benefit.

Comment: Why do you want to ping the public IP from within the VPC?

Comment: i am running elastic search on that public ip and i don't want everyone to access it so that's why

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by blocking `0.0.0.0/0` on instance B. The solution was to add a rule to the B's security group allowing traffic from its public IP.

In case of internet traffic, rules cannot reference each other by security groups. The SG to SG traffic is only for private IP addresses.